# Get source code of "fit" function from StMoMo in R

Tags: r, function, package

I am using StMoMo package to project future mortality improvements. So far, the accuracy have been abysmal. I am trying to look into the `fit` function in the StMoMo package to see if it can offer any insights (such as parameters and how they're sued, and if there are ways to tune the parameters).

I have tried the following:

1. `fit`

   `function (object, ...) 
   UseMethod("fit")
   <bytecode: 0x17f55d10>
   <environment: namespace:StMoMo>`
2. `edit(getAnywhere('fit'))` as proposed by user @smci

   `structure(list("fit", structure(list(function (object, ...) 
   UseMethod("fit"), function (object, ...) 
   UseMethod("fit")), .Names = c("package:StMoMo", "")), c("package:StMoMo", 
   "namespace:StMoMo"), c(TRUE, FALSE), c(FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("name", 
   "objs", "where", "visible", "dups"), class = "getAnywhere")`
3. `getAnywhere(fit)`

   `A single object matching ‘fit’ was found
   It was found in the following places
     package:StMoMo
     namespace:StMoMo
   with value`

   `function (object, ...) 
   UseMethod("fit")
   <bytecode: 0x1e3ed4e0>
   <environment: namespace:StMoMo>`
4. I tried to go into the library folder in my R directory, and I found StMoMo. I am not exactly sure which folder would contain the source code, if they do.

I am not sure I understand the information obtained through the tries above. So my question here is: is there a simpler way to know where to find the source code of a function from a package, let it be in a folder or through typing some code.

Thanks.

Comment: `getAnywhere(fit.StMoMo)`. It works. What you want is the method for objects of class `"StMoMo"`, not the generic function `fit`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yep you saved the day; thank you! Now, how would I know that there is a generic fit function? Because before loading StMoMo, when I typed in "fit", it says "Error: object 'fit' not found". So I assumed that there is no generic "fit" function.

Comment: That means that the package creates the generic and its methods. Generally speaking, modeling functions output objects of special classes (`lm`, etc) and there are methods to get what users need. So you could have know by checking `class(object)` and then tried the above when you would have seen `"StMoMo"`.

Comment: When you see the body of a function is `UseMethod("fit")`, you know it's a generic function.  (Some of them do a little bit more, but most don't.)